# Axios запрос не работает(CORS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, axios, cors

Следующий запрос Axios произведенный через локальный сервер на Redux не работает, выдавая CORS ошибку:

```
        axios.post('url_сервера', qs.stringify({ 

          "username": "123", 
          "password": "123", 
          "repassword": "123"

        }, { 

          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          },

        }))
```

При этом запрос выполняется через Postman, и даже следующий python код:

```
import requests
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict

url = "url_сервера"

headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

data = "username='123'&password='123'&repassword='123'"

resp = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)

print(resp.content)
```

Доступ к серверу отсутствует от слова совсем. Может дело в каких нибудь загаловках или чем нибудь подобным?

Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ в сети:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело действительно в заголовках. Следуя [статье на mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) сервер, на который вы отправляете запросы, должен в заголовках ответа на запрос методом `OPTIONS` отправлять `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (в вашем случае значение должно быть `localhost:3000`) и `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` (для запроса из примера значение должно быть `POST`).

Если у вас нет доступа к серверу и возможности добавить в его ответ заголовки, браузер из соображений безопасности не позволит вам делать на него запросы. Возможным выходом в такой ситуации может стать контролируемый вами прокси-сервер. Например, тот сервер, который запущен у вас локально на порте 3000 или [webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy).